# How do I randomize the order of messages in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Suppose I have m messages in queue, and I have n messages need to publish. How do I insert the n messages in the queue in a random order in stead of appending to the end of the queue? in another words, How can I use rabbitMQ to shuffle?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a queue.

Comment: well, i have a special use case riro, random in, random out

Comment: that is, by definition, not a queue.

Answer (score 8):

There is no built in way to randomize the order of messages in the queue.  However, RabbitMQ does support priority queues, in which you can set a priority for messages (between 0 and 255), and messages with the lowest priority will be consumed first.  You could specify a random priority for each message, and it would give you a pseudo-randomization of the queue.

[RabbitMQ Documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html)

Comment: Based on the documentation, messages with higher priority (higher integer value) will be consumed first.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use rabbitMQ to shuffle?

you can't. not within RabbitMQ, directly, at least.

all queues in RMQ are FIFO - first in, first out. the order in which the messages are put into a queue is the order in which they will be delivered to a consumer.

If you want to randomize the order in which messages are put into the queue, you must do that from your code in your message producer.